# mysql, add conditions to max()?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, t1 and t2

**t1**

```
key id  product  price  date  
0   0   cheese   23     02/09/15  
1   0   cheese   30     02/10/15  
2   1   eggs     3      01/11/15  
3   2   cheese   22     04/11/15
```

**t2**

```
key  product    min_price  min_date  
0    cheese     22         03/11/15  
1    cheese     19         02/11/15  
2    cheese     15         01/13/15  
3    eggs        3         01/10/15
```

I wish to create a table like t1 but also showing the min_price and min_date from t2, which corresponds to a date immediately BEFORE any date in t1 as grouped by id:

**new table**

```
key id  product  price date        min_price  min_date  
0   0   cheese   23    02/09/15    15         01/13/15  
1   0   cheese   30    02/10/15    15         01/13/15  
2   1   eggs     3     01/11/15    3          01/10/15   
3   2   cheese   22    04/11/15    22         03/11/15
```

How do I get the new table with mysql?
Many many thanks!

Comment: How do you intend to link cheese with id = 2 on t1 with t2?

Comment: @Rodney: for id = 2, the date in t1 is 04/11, mysql should look for the most recent price in t2 BEFORE that date, which is 03/11 in the example. Think of t2 as a cost price list that is constantly updated and I want to know what the actual sale price (in t1) was. Thanks!

Comment: Step 1. Store dates as DATEs

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what's going on with all your `keys` and `ids` (and I doubt you do either), so I've ignored them...

Consider the following...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t1;

CREATE TABLE t1
(product  VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,price  INT NOT NULL
,date  DATE NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(product,price)
);

INSERT INTO t1 VALUES
('cheese',23,'2015-02-09'),
('cheese',30,'2015-02-10'),
('eggs',3,'2015-01-11'),
('cheese',22,'2015-04-11');


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t2;

CREATE TABLE t2
(product VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,min_price INT NOT NULL 
,min_date DATE NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(product,min_date)
);

INSERT INTO t2 VALUES
('cheese',22,'2015-03-11'),
('cheese',19,'2015-02-11'),
('cheese',15,'2015-01-13'),
('eggs',3,'2015-01-10');
```

This query returns the latest (i.e. maximum) `min_date` from t2 less than the t1 date associated with a given product...

```
   SELECT t1.*
        , MAX(min_date) min_date 
     FROM t1 
     JOIN t2 
       ON t2.product = t1.product 
      AND t2.min_date <= t1.date 
    GROUP 
       BY t1.product, t1.date
```

To get the associated t2.min_price, just join t2  back onto that result...

```
SELECT a.*
     , b.min_price 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT t1.*
            , MAX(min_date) min_date 
         FROM t1 
         JOIN t2 
           ON t2.product = t1.product 
          AND t2.min_date <= t1.date 
        GROUP 
           BY t1.product, t1.date
      ) a 
   JOIN t2 b 
     ON b.product = a.product 
    AND b.min_date = a.min_date;
+---------+-------+------------+------------+-----------+
| product | price | date       | min_date   | min_price |
+---------+-------+------------+------------+-----------+
| cheese  |    23 | 2015-02-09 | 2015-01-13 |        15 |
| cheese  |    30 | 2015-02-10 | 2015-01-13 |        15 |
| cheese  |    22 | 2015-04-11 | 2015-03-11 |        22 |
| eggs    |     3 | 2015-01-11 | 2015-01-10 |         3 |
+---------+-------+------------+------------+-----------+
```

Comment: I have not got back to the problem yet, but thanks so much @Strawberry!